# UIToolbar acting super weird while adding items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

This is my problem.

I have 4 different UIToolbars in my application. And I have 5 BarButton items allocated and initialized. (all are properties and they are all alloc init 'ed in the beginning).

I add all five bar buttons in 4 separate NSArrays alloc init 'ed, and assign those arrays to all 4 toolbars. Incidentally, the last toolbar is the one visible. The other toolbars are blank.

***In other words....***

Should i alloc init a separate set of bar buttons items for each toolbar ??? In that case it works. If I share buttons, only the last toolbar added to the buttons seem to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not weird, it's expected
Each instance of a UIView can only be present one subview at the time.
Let's say this:
You hava a UIView instance and it's added twice to two separated superviews
How do you distinguish which one was touched so you adjust it to interact?
You need to make and instance for each Button/UIView

Or this, you have a UIView (UIBarButton, whatever) and you need to know it's superview, if it's added to two UIToolbars, which one is it?